# Does there exist an idempotent, pseudo-constant $p$-adic function with an uncountable image?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, idempotents

$f$ is defined to be a pseudo-constant function if $f'(x)=0$.

The question simply comes from idly wondering, "What are p-adic idempotent functions like?" Differentiable idempotent functions satisfy $f(f(x))=f(x)$ as well as its derivative $f'(f(x))f'(x)=f'(x)$.

If $f'(x)$ is nonzero for all $x$, then we have $f'(f(x))=1$ which is to be expected since if the image of $f$ is $A$, then for all $a \in A$ we have $f(a)=a$ is the identity function.

If $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$, then we have a pseudo-constant function. We can create a pseudo-constant idempotent function by partitioning $\mathbb{Z}_p$ into disjoint balls, each with a distinguished center, and create a locally constant function that maps a point in each of these balls to their center.

This last example can at most produce a pseudo-constant function with a countable image, since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ only has countably many distinct balls in its topology. On the other hand, I am aware of pseudo-constant functions with uncountably large images, but I see no reason why there couldn't also be idempotent ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image $I$ of a pseudo-constant, idempotent $f:\mathbb Z_p \rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ is, in fact, finite.

Namely, for all $x,y \in I$, $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} =1$, so for $f' \equiv 0$ it is necessary that for every $x \in I$ there is $\varepsilon_x >0$ with $B_{\varepsilon_x} (x) \cap I = \{x\}$. The collection of all $B_{\varepsilon_x} (x)$ ($x\in I$) is an open cover of $I$.

But as pseudo-constant maps are continuous, $I$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you, thats helps a lot and completely rules out compact domains. Now that I realize I have to focus on noncompact domains, an example I've found with countable image is $f(x)=p^{v_p(x)}$ as a map $f:\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \to \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. I'll be giving this more thought this week and suspect we can push your argument a bit further towards ruling out some of the noncompact cases too.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb Z_p \setminus \{0\}$, right?(Otherwise that set is compact, and the map is constant.)

Comment: Well unless I'm mistaken, this implies immediately that $f(S)$ is countable for any set $S$ which is a countable union of compact sets. And unless I'm mistaken, any open subset of e.g. any local field is of that kind.

Comment: Yes, I only meant to exclude $0$ not all of $p\mathbb{Z}_p$! I was originally thinking about $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$, so either is fine. I've had a moment to sit down and yes you're correct on your last comment which ties up the loose end. Thanks.